Connection Raspberry Pi on Ubuntu Core with SSH
I have an raspberry pi 4b. I burned an image for ubuntucore like this "ubuntu-core-22-arm64+raspi.img.xz".
enter image description here
So i created an Ubuntu one account. I downloaded PuttyGen and generated a ssh-key. I imported the SSH-key I created into the Ubuntu One account. Then I started the raspberry pi which has ubuntu core. I made the wifi settings and entered my ubuntu one email.
While I was at the stage in the image, I logged in as user@host via putty. What is the password requested in the opened console? where can i reach it? Even though I tried all the passwords I have, the password is not approved. and I get "No supported authentication methods available(Server sent:publickey)" as a warning. I tried various things found on the forum but it didn't solve my problem. I installed Ubuntu Core again and again and tried it with a different Ubuntu One account.
Can you make a suggestion?

Your Ubuntu Core login name ("user") must be your Ubuntu One account username ("susan-smith").

Ubuntu Core fetches your Ubuntu One public SSH key for the first login.

Your IP address comes from the Ubuntu Core screen or from your router, and may change at every reboot. Depends upon how your network is set up.
ssh susan-smith@192.168.1.69
A password prompt usually means one of the following:

You are not using your Ubuntu One username.
Keyboard/Language confusion.
Your Ubuntu Core system cannot reach the internet.
Occasionally, it means that the Ubuntu Core system's IP address has changed, and you are trying to connect to the wrong system. This is a common cause of login problems on the second boot, the boot into a working system after setup is complete.


What did you mean "Ubuntu Core Login name"?, how can i set it up?
As you say i conneted it with"enesaytemiz@192.168.1.32" . Result was same

"Ubuntu Core login name" = ssh "username" field. Is "enesaytemiz" your Ubuntu One account name?

Yes. it is enesaytemiz
